# Error SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; Error after alias

Tags: php, mysql

I am receiving the following error when I am trying to run a simple select on my database:

```
select count(id) as rows from table-name
```

> Error SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'rows from table-name' at line 1

When I run the same command as:

```
select count(id) as `rows` from table-name
```

it works properly.

The problem is that the first code is working on my production environment and I can`t change all SQL for the application, I believe that is something related to collation but I tried several and the problem persists.

> MySQL version on production is 5.6 and dev is 8.0.3

Comment: What flavor and version of mysql are you using?

Comment: is `rows` a reserved word ?

Comment: It's a keyword @nogad

Comment: i guess right, send me cookie

Comment: "ROWS: became reserved in 8.0.2" - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#ftn.idm139649184199728

Comment: See, this is where the version becomes important!

Comment: Unfortunately we still do not know what version the OP is using @aynber

Comment: @JayBlanchard Exactly. Until they answer, we're just shooting in the dark.

Comment: In the latest MariaDB stable release `ROWS` is also a **reserved** keyword.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Since he's getting the error that would happen if it's reserved, it seems pretty safe to assume that he's using one of these recent versions. Similar to guessing the version if they're getting the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` error.

Comment: it seems that the problem is the version. I will recreate my environment with 5.6 Thanks @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `rows` is the reserved keyword in MySql. However

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ROWS
```

Just works fine in my system. May you're local sytem is windows and server is using linux.

Now changing this depends on how organized your code is. Now a days developers use framework. So you've used one of good PHP framework, then you don't have to worry, Just update the table variable value with new one and rename the table in db and things should go fine.

In case you can not do that the download whole code to local server. And use some good editor i.e [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/). and first find for the `rows` keyword used through out the application and then if you feel safe, just use find and replace. Bang! and upload the code again. Should work fine again.